# Ethereum mining issue

Tags: mining, wallets

Installed the latest Ethereum windows client , both in home and office network . I see subtle differences when its mines with Testnet.

When in office , I see it always mines new blocks and in home network  it starts importing as the immediate next steps. In office network its is not connected to testnet outside as i don't see any peers connected. while in home i  see peers connected and it tries to download the whole blocks .

As i use ethereum client to acess both nodes , Why am i unable to connect to other peers in office . I do understand their will be firewall issues , but then my node should not mine itself . I am not clear on why its self mining when its not connected out .

Logs below

1) From  office node

```
I1116 11:19:56.836850 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata
I1116 11:19:56.850851 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata
I1116 11:19:56.852851 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata
I1116 11:19:56.892853 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 16MB cache and 16 file handles to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\dapp
I1116 11:19:56.898853 eth/backend.go:172] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 2
I1116 11:19:56.898853 core/genesis.go:92] Genesis block already in chain. Writing canonical number
I1116 11:19:56.898853 eth/backend.go:180] Successfully wrote custom genesis block: 0cd786a2425d16f152c658316c423e6ce1181e15c3295826d7c9904cba9ce303
I1116 11:19:56.898853 eth/backend.go:201] Blockchain DB Version: 3
I1116 11:19:56.900853 core/blockchain.go:214] Last header: #918 [641bfed3…] TD=127765120
I1116 11:19:56.900853 core/blockchain.go:215] Last block: #918 [641bfed3…] TD=127765120
I1116 11:19:56.900853 core/blockchain.go:216] Fast block: #918 [641bfed3…] TD=127765120
I1116 11:19:56.900853 eth/handler.go:114] blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled
I1116 11:19:56.902854 p2p/server.go:313] Starting Server
I1116 11:19:58.945970 p2p/discover/udp.go:217] Listening, enode://8f9345c2a2e4eb830406b431342a67e045277d6a099dbadc612f6ae6704a680066419ab9ca8e9ac3b6e91df354351fe61ed288e459555993c823c9211b08fbc0@0.0.0.0:30303
I1116 11:19:58.956971 p2p/server.go:556] Listening on [::]:30303
I1116 11:19:58.958971 node/node.go:296] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
I1116 11:20:17.832051 eth/backend.go:454] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG ON (ethash dir: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Ethash)
I1116 11:20:17.832051 miner/miner.go:119] Starting mining operation (CPU=1 TOT=2)
I1116 11:20:17.832051 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Ethash)
I1116 11:20:17.833051 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 919 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 1.0001ms
I1116 11:20:17.833051 ethash.go:259] Generating DAG for epoch 0 (size 1073739904) (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
I1116 11:20:47.695759 ethash.go:276] Done generating DAG for epoch 0, it took 29.862708s
I1116 11:21:26.476977 miner/worker.go:342]   Mined block (#919 / d281aea0). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I1116 11:21:26.476977 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 920 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 0s
```

2) From home node

```
I1116 08:53:03.014558 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/admin/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata
I1116 08:53:03.120005 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/admin/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata
I1116 08:53:03.120552 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/admin/.ethereum/testnet/chaindata
I1116 08:53:03.159311 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 16MB cache and 16 file handles to /home/admin/.ethereum/testnet/dapp
I1116 08:53:03.161476 eth/backend.go:172] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 2
I1116 08:53:03.162021 core/genesis.go:92] Genesis block already in chain. Writing canonical number
I1116 08:53:03.162072 eth/backend.go:180] Successfully wrote custom genesis block: 0cd786a2425d16f152c658316c423e6ce1181e15c3295826d7c9904cba9ce303
I1116 08:53:03.162119 eth/backend.go:201] Blockchain DB Version: 3
I1116 08:53:03.163257 core/blockchain.go:214] Last header: #1 [ad474131…] TD=262144
I1116 08:53:03.163277 core/blockchain.go:215] Last block: #733466 [60207b3e…] TD=18580056623328
I1116 08:53:03.163283 core/blockchain.go:216] Fast block: #1 [ad474131…] TD=262144
I1116 08:53:03.163523 eth/handler.go:114] blockchain not empty, fast sync disabled
I1116 08:53:03.164392 p2p/server.go:313] Starting Server
I1116 08:53:05.262933 p2p/discover/udp.go:217] Listening, enode://aa794aed2387bd40ab9ccbd34c8f390cb1ad255da287349e5221899694783a8bbb6d4e80a916a1adebd22f152267f9047ed052f7507e530bb40d146a72073482@[::]:30303
I1116 08:53:05.264009 p2p/server.go:556] Listening on [::]:30303
I1116 08:53:05.275000 node/node.go:296] IPC endpoint opened: /home/admin/.ethereum/geth.ipc
I1116 08:53:15.264965 eth/downloader/downloader.go:319] Block synchronisation started
I1116 08:53:18.639232 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 2 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 5 txs in 1.727807199s. #733468 [5357f08b / 804baeb7]
I1116 08:53:26.649472 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 14 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 54 txs in 8.007118921s. #733482 [756c5176 / c5087d9b]
I1116 08:53:32.381528 miner/miner.go:109] Can not start mining operation due to network sync (starts when finished)
I1116 08:53:32.381555 eth/backend.go:454] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG ON (ethash dir: /home/admin/.ethash)
I1116 08:53:32.381605 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /home/admin/.ethash)
I1116 08:53:34.686174 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 61 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 107 txs in 8.036689713s. #733543 [c5087d9b / 23d88fcb]
I1116 08:53:42.855455 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 38 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 64 txs in 8.169291292s. #733581 [23d88fcb / c10b8113]
I1116 08:53:50.904279 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 64 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 75 txs in 8.048815351s. #733645 [c10b8113 / 332895b0]
I1116 08:53:58.925573 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 36 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 84 txs in 8.021294312s. #733681 [332895b0 / 282533fa]
I1116 08:54:06.991803 core/blockchain.go:1001] imported 48 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 63 txs in 8.066222288s. #733729 [282533fa
```

Comment: Which commands did you use to start both the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

As you said:

It seems the main difference is the connection:

- Your office node is not connecting to other peers (probably by firewall/corporate proxy/other security measures). So it considers the Blockchain as synced, so starts mining new blocks to get rewards.
- Your home node, otherwise, can get other peers, so it realizes there are many blocks it does not own. So before mining, your home node starts syncing the blockchain.

Solutions:

- If you don't want your office node to mine: type in console `miner.stop()`.
- If you want to connect your office node to other peers: first try manually the admin.addPeer("nodeadresshere"). If you still get no peers, then contact your IT dept.

Comment: thanks @kaneikDev . admin.addPeer() doesnt work . BTW , it does get any error also to the geth console . I would had suppose at least some connection error . It returns true

Comment: if admin.addPeer is not working, then you're having some firewall/proxy connection block. You should talk with your IT dept to solve this issue.

Comment: Tried in a private network and it worked. Thanks  for your help  . Disabled discovery and then added :-)

Comment: great then :)
keep going with your investigations :)